# Transform and Pivot in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**Please  can you help me find this syntax on mysql**

```
TRANSFORM Sum(CCur([Détails commandes].[Prix unitaire]*[Quantité]*(1-[Remise (%)])/100)*100) AS MontantProduit
SELECT Produits.[Nom du produit], Commandes.[Code client], Year([Date commande]) AS AnnéeCommande
FROM Produits INNER JOIN (Commandes INNER JOIN [Détails commandes] ON Commandes.[N° commande] = [Détails commandes].[N° commande]) ON Produits.[Réf produit] = [Détails commandes].[Réf produit]
WHERE (((Commandes.[Date commande]) Between #1/1/1997# And #12/31/1997#))
GROUP BY Produits.[Nom du produit], Commandes.[Code client], Year([Date commande])
PIVOT "Trim " & DatePart("q",[Date commande],1) In ("Trim 1","Trim 2","Trim 3","Trim 4");
```

Comment: Une transformation dans Access est un "pivot dynamique" dans MySQL. A transform in Access is a "dynamic pivot" in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:
SELECT `Produits`.`Nom du produit`, `Commandes`.`Code client`, Year(`Date commande`) AS `AnnéeCommande`,
sum(case when QUARTER(`Commandes`.`Date commande`) = 1 then ((`Détails commandes`.`Prix unitaire`*`Détails commandes`.`Quantité`*(1-`Détails commandes`.`Remise (%)`)/100)*100) end) AS `TRIM 1`,
sum(case when QUARTER(`Commandes`.`Date commande`) = 2 then ((`Détails commandes`.`Prix unitaire`*`Détails commandes`.`Quantité`*(1-`Détails commandes`.`Remise (%)`)/100)*100) end) AS `TRIM 2`,
sum(case when QUARTER(`Commandes`.`Date commande`) = 3 then ((`Détails commandes`.`Prix unitaire`*`Détails commandes`.`Quantité`*(1-`Détails commandes`.`Remise (%)`)/100)*100) end) AS `TRIM 3`,
sum(case when QUARTER(`Commandes`.`Date commande`) = 4 then ((`Détails commandes`.`Prix unitaire`*`Détails commandes`.`Quantité`*(1-`Détails commandes`.`Remise (%)`)/100)*100) end) AS `TRIM 4`
FROM `Produits` INNER JOIN (`Commandes` INNER JOIN `Détails commandes` ON `Commandes`.`N° commande` = `Détails commandes`.`N° commande`) ON `Produits`.`Réf produit` = `Détails commandes`.`Réf produit`
WHERE (((`Commandes`.`Date commande`) Between '1997-01-01' And '1997-12-31'))
GROUP BY `Produits`.`Nom du produit`, `Commandes`.`Code client`, Year(`Commandes`.`Date commande`)